# Is it appropriate for my manager to make me share my credentials?

Tags: manager, legal

Recently, at work, I was assigned a license for Microsoft Visual Studio and was asked to create an official Microsoft ID. The license came with benefits like a trial account for six months at Pluralsight.com. Upon learning about it my manager asked the three microsoft technology developers to activate the benefits in staggered pattern. Then share their credentials at pluralsight with all the members of the group including BAs, QAs, Java Developers located on shore as well as off shore. Is this even legal and should I comply or push back and say no to her?

Comment: Are the accounts linked? Can you change the password of the PluralSight account to be something you don't use and would be comfortable sharing? At the end of the day the company owns your work email account.

Comment: Yes, the accounts are linked...the work microsoft account and pluralsight account...I can change the password of the PluralSight account...Read their T & C and it seems against it to share credentials in this manner...Thought the language makes it difficult to make it out at once...

Comment: If this instruction was verbal from your manager and they revoke the access because it was abused, then your company may blame you for the loss...

Comment: Was the request made in writing?  Better, ensure that it is in writing.  E-mail your manager asking who the credentials were going to be sent to.

Comment: The request was verbal...I would be the one emailing everyone from my official id...The email would go out to everyone in the group BAs, QAs, Developers, Managers all of them on shore as well as off shore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even legal

This will depend on the pluralsight.com terms and conditions and/or licence granted with your trial. I imagine it would be against those terms to share your credentials, and may be against them to chain trials in a single organisation like that, but that will entirely depend on how they've written that contract.

Your company presumably owns the Visual Studio licence, so (again depending on the terms of that) they almost certainly have the right to the corresponding benefits as well.

Whether this is ethical is another matter.

> and should I comply or push back and say no to her?

<s>Personally I would comply and consider this a fight not worth "dying in a ditch" over. You will also benefit from the chained pluralsight membership. It is a bit dodgy, and might well violate the pluralsight T&Cs, but how important is that to you?</s>

**Edit:** In light of what you've clarified in comments, I would not comply with this verbal request.

I would send an email to her saying that although you see the possible benefits of her request that you share credentials (worth spelling out, in neutral terms, what she asked for), given the pluralsight T&Cs and general IT security implications you're worried that it could put the company in a difficult position.

Personally I would leave it there: I wouldn't explicitly refuse to comply, and I wouldn't invite her to reply. If your email requires no response most likely she will never mention it again; if she does overrule your objections then you have them in writing, and you can probably inoffensively ask her to put her instruction in writing too ("Ah ok thanks, I'm just handling something else right now, could you quickly reply to that email I sent just so it doesn't slip my mind?"), in which case you're covered.

Comment: The thing is...This Sr. Manager and another manager in the group got pulled up just days ago for sharing windows credentials...which had access to production databases...The email chain which I am privy to...The DB admins used harsh language stating that it could lead to disciplinary action against both including and up to termination...This was just a few days back...The company is big, actually huge, lots of groups within IT and seems like by listening to her, I would be putting myself in the line of fire...

Comment: Fair enough, as you say sharing Windows credentials is very serious so this is a bad pattern of behaviour. You definitely don't want to get caught up in it if there is a lot of attention on her and IT discover that she's done it again, with your help. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your company is huge, you most likely have a legal department. Ask your boss to check with the legal department that this is all Ok. Then check with the IT guys privately that it is Ok as well - if there is sensitive company information stored by PluralSight (I have no idea what the software does) that could be leaked if you share credentials.

Comment: Did not mean to brag about the company being huge (Fortune 200, Biggest player in the Waste Vertical though)...By huge I meant egos the size of Jupiter...Asking manager to check with legal would not go down too well with her...Does not even open the secured doors herself...guards run up and swipe her in and if not, she just stands there with arms folded bristling with anger...tells on the guard to her husband the director...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even legal

I am not a lawyer so I can not definitively speak to its legality, but in most cases this would be a violation of the terms of service. These companies make money by permitting individual access to their content. Sharing the content reduces their potential revenue.

> and should I comply or push back and say no to her?

The chances of you being detected and prosecuted is vanishingly small, but there is still a risk. This is also an ethical matter, and if you succumb to an unethical request, you may be expected to do so again in the future. And the next time the risk could be greater.

If it were me I would first decline in writing, in a friendly hey-I-just-found-out manner, stating the appropriate terms of service. If your manager still insists, I would give her the credentials (in writing again) and request that she change the email to her own email, and the password to something she knows. That way she has taken ownership of the account. Then don't use the account -- you will no longer responsible for what happens.

If you try to go over your manager's head to another department (essentially reporting her unethical behavior) that will not go well for you.